# User Data vs Ansible in Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ansible, terraform, devops

I'm working on deploying some servers in the AWS cloud with another engineer.
We have written the IaC in Terraform and Terragrunt to provision an Auto-scaling Group. We were wondering what would be the proper approach for configuring the ec2 instances that are created by the ASG:

- Ansible or,
- Use the User Data in the launch configuration to run a bash script

In the user data script, we are writing some configuration files, importing some secrets and running a few containers.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer totally depends on you!

If you *already* have ansible playbooks that you can run locally, I'd use them!

If you *already* have bash scripts that can bootstrap your instances, I'd use them!

Either way, you'll need to utilize [user-data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#user_data) to either:

- Install Ansible, load your playbooks and run
- Simply run your bash code

What matters here is what works best for your team to understand and to maintain over time

I'd personally recommend using only bash within [user-data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html#user_data) because it reduces complexity (less need to learn Ansible for an engineer unfamiliar with it)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I will always prefer for bash or power-shell script to invoked through user data rather than Ansible as I am more comfortable to write bash/powershell scripts. So basically, its choice and how convenient you are in Ansible. If you need any sample user data code to invoke bash, pls let me know.